# Twig lexer : add delimiter

Tags: php, twig, lexer

I want to use Twig (v1.15.0) in my project in order to replace our homemade template engine. It uses specific delimiters to replace variables, [[...]], or to manage localized strings, [% ... %].

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>[%myLocalizedString%]</td>
        <td>[[myVarToReplace]]</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I don't want to modify all existing templates to replace each delimiter, for legacy and compatibility reasons.

For variables, it is not a big deal, I just have to set the Twig lexer's options :

```
$twig = new Twig_Environment();

$lexer = new Twig_Lexer($twig, array(
    'tag_comment'   => array('{#', '#}'),
    'tag_block'     => array('{%', '%}'),
    'tag_variable'  => array('[[', ']]'), // was array('{{', '}}')
    'interpolation' => array('#{', '}'),
));
$twig->setLexer($lexer);
```

In the case of localization delimiters is not as simple. Initialy I wanted to do something like that :

```
$twig = new Twig_Environment();
$lexer = new Twig_Lexer($twig);
$lexer->addDelimiter('tag_localize', array('[%', '%]'), 'functionToCall');
```

But it does not seems to be implemented yet.

The ultimate solution is to extend the Lexer class and use it in my twig environnement.
But I would like to avoid that.

Is there any better solution ?

Comment: Can you state an example how exactly a localization tag look like in your old template engine?

Comment: This will translate  "Hello world" according to user locale :  [%Hello world%]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure you know this already: in Twig you do translations using the I18n extension. That extension provides a "trans" tag: [see i18n docs](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/extensions/i18n.html)

I see no way you can convert your translation syntax `[%Hello world%]` into the Twig way `{% trans %}Hello world{% endtrans %}` by extendling the Lexer class, because `{%` is a block element and `trans` a tag defined in the I18n extension. You could build your own translation logic, but I think it is much easier to create a preprocessor that replaces `[%` with `{% trans %]` and  `%}` with `{% endtrans %}`.

I imagine it could work like this (untested):

```
class MYTwigEnvironment extends Twig_Environment {
   public function compileSource($source, $name = null) {
     /* 
      * code to replace '[%' with '{% trans %}' in $source 
      * comes here ...
      */
     return parent::compileSource($source, $name = null);
   }
}
```

As far as I understand, this way the template caching should stay intact.

regards

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Currently in my controllers with a boolean I'm choosing between twig or our homemade template engine. I think your solution will suit my needs and allows me to remove this horror. Actually this is what I'm doing by hand when rewriting some existing templates (the software claims to implement MVC, but because of poorly written ex-template engine, controllers may contain html...). It would have been easier if Twig allowed to create others delimiters... maybe for a future release !